# Android Firebase:To retrieve single user data and custom login without using login providers like google,facebook etc

Tags: android, firebase

I need to give a custom login. I don't want to use login providers like google, facebook,etc. I need old school single data retrieval of users info(name and phone in my case) and if user data is found in the database then redirect to home page.I have tried something and it's not working.

java snippet
................................................

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editTextname;
EditText editTextphone;
Button buttonlogin;
Spinner spinnerdesignation;

DatabaseReference rootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    editTextname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    editTextphone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
    spinnerdesignation=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.designation);
    buttonlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findUser();
        }
    });

}

public void findUser(){
    String designation=spinnerdesignation.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(designation=="Faculty"){
       rootRef.child("Faculty").orderByChild("facultyName").equalTo(editTextname.toString()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             Map<String,String> map=dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
             String phoneNumber=map.get("facultyPhone");

             if(phoneNumber==editTextphone.toString()){
                 Intent intent=new               Intent(getApplicationContext(),FacultyActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });
    }
}
```

}

database

```
-Root
 -Faculty
   -Kg5Qe482G7xEn9rYLXn
     facultyDept:"computer science"
     facultyDesignation: "HOD"
     facultyEmail: "ajaskjfjaj@gmail.com"
     facultyID: "-Kg5Qe482G7xEn9rYLXn"
     facultyName: "john"
     facultyPhone: "1234567891"
   -Kg5QjXQIZeuwvHi22WH

 -Student
   -Kg-Jg1f68RXb4N47sbA
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String#equals` method when comparing strings. Do not use `==`.